# How to update spring jpa many to many relationship and json format to do so

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

maybe another many-to-many relationship issue with spring data-jpa and how to update an existing entity with another existing entities.
I'll put a short version of my Entities just for clarify only when the error occurs.

I have a Peticion entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "peticiones")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = 
ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,property = "id", scope = 
Peticion.class)
@Validated
public class Peticion
{

private int id;

private Usuario usuario;

private Categoria categoria;

private Set<Tag> tags;

@ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {
        CascadeType.MERGE
    } )
@JoinTable( name="peticion_tag", joinColumns= @JoinColumn(name = "peticion_id", referencedColumnName="id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id") )
public Set<Tag> getTags() {
    return tags;
}

public void setTags(Set<Tag> tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
}
```

And Tag entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tags")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = 
ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,property = "id", scope = 
Tag.class)
public class Tag
{

private int id;

@Size( min = 4 )
private String nombre;

private Set<Peticion> peticiones;

private Set<Categoria> categorias;

private Set<Usuario> usuarios;

@ManyToMany( mappedBy="tags" )
public Set<Peticion> getPeticiones() {
    return peticiones;
}

public void setPeticiones(Set<Peticion> peticiones) {
    this.peticiones = peticiones;
}
```

Ok, so when I try to put or patch one Peticion in the format of:
    {
        "id": 123,
        "usuario":{
            "id": 5
        },
        "categoria":{
            "id": 7
        },
        "tags":[
            {
                "id":3
            },
            {
                "id":10
            }
        ]
    }

When I send this information, I got an error that says that I have a constraint violation saying that **name** I suppose the one property for Tag is null... So I figure it out that this is trying to create another entity, but that's not the case I wanna do, I wanna update the relationships between Peticion and Tag, and for example if I do this:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "usuario":{
        "id": 5
    },
    "categoria":{
        "id": 7
    },
    "tags":[]
}
```

It works perfectly, I mean it deletes the relationship tags that were before. So I don't know if I'm sending the json correctly or do I have to put another configuration annotation or something in my Entities.
Note: I'm using JpaRepository for saving/updating and my controller only calls the method save.

Thank you

Comment: Try to change CascadeType.MERGE to CascadeType.REMOVE.

Comment: @AdamLesiak this works!!! but IDK why... could you explain it to me?? thank you...

Comment: When you have CascadeType.MERGE empty "tags" in JSON says to JPA to try to save related tags. You tags are empty and JPA try to save empty tags so there is a constraint violation because tags have no data. When you have CascadeTYpe.REMOVE this affect only when you will remove the Petition entity. CascadeType.REMOVE does not affects on insert/update.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing fetches on the relation entity on your database layer, I think you should also share the repositories and queries that you use to fetch the linked data.